# Send message from several Java threads

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I want to use ExecutorService in order to use several Java Threads for sending and receiving message with RabbitMQ:

```
public class EndPoint {

    public ExecutorService es;  
    public EndPoint(String endpointName) throws Exception {     
        es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);          
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();            
        connection = factory.newConnection(es);
        channel = connection.createChannel();
        ..........
    }

    private static EndPoint single_instance = null; 
    public static EndPoint getInstance() throws Exception
    {
        if (single_instance == null)
            single_instance = new EndPoint(null);

        return single_instance;
    }
}
```

In some remote class:

```
EndPoint vvvv = EndPoint.getInstance();
vvvv.es.execute(some content);
```

How I can send and receive data from several threads? So far the code that I managed to create.

```
channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, endPointName, null, SerializationUtils.serialize(object));
```

But how the above code and be used with Java Thread?

Comment: Just some slight suggestions: 1) make `es` final aka "readonly", 2) make the constructor `private`, 3) remove the constructor parameter `endpointName` (seems like it's always null, as you're only creating one instance)

Comment: @Lino thanks. Can you give me some code example about the issue please?

Comment: You should read their API https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html . They say not to share the channel between multiple threads but you can invoke certain operations on this single channel. You have not given any operations you want to invoke here other than "basicPublish". You need to go find what more operations that they allow.

Comment: Do you know how I can use multiple threads with RabbitMQ? Probably with different channel for each thread?